# Where is chrome.app officially documented?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Looking over http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html , I was unable to find any documentation for `chrome.app`.  I have no trouble getting `chrome.app.getDetails()` to work, but am wondering if there is any form of official documentation (or why not, if not).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`chrome.app` has since been deprecated.  However, its functionality has been moved the [`chrome.runtime`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime), mostly within [`chrome.runtime.getManifest()`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getManifest).

Comment: Note that this answer is only true for Chrome **extensions**. The `chrome.app` namespace still exists for [Chrome **apps**](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html), e.g. [`chrome.app.window`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app.window.html) and [`chrome.app.runtime`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app.runtime.html).

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the reason that it's not documented is simple oversight. The `chrome.app` API is put together in a different way than most of the other extension APIs (it's pieced together manually in [renderer/resources/extensions/app.js](http://code.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/renderer/resources/extensions/app.js) rather than being automatically assembled from JSON files like [extension.json](http://code.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/common/extensions/api/extension.json)). We use those JSON files to autogenerate much of the documentation, so a missing JSON file means missing docs.

Would you mind filing a bug at http://new.crbug.com/? I'll make sure it gets in front of the team.

Comment: It turns out to be in the system already ( [Issue 111354](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111354&q=chrome.app%20label%3Adocumentation&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary) )

Comment: I've thrown it into the correct queue and CCd the tech writer. It won't happen right away, as I think we'll prefer to write something to automate the documentation rather than building a one-off, but it'll get done. Thanks for the report.

Comment: Definitely not right away, one year after `chrome.app.getDetails()` remains undocumented.

Comment: @cprcrack: Well, it's also deprecated.  Use [`chrome.runtime.getManifest()`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#method-getManifest).

Answer (score 4):

While the chrome.app.getDetails() function (like rest of chrome.app) remains undocumented, there is already a documented alternative for that function in chrome.runtime.getManifest().

Documentation for chrome.runtime.getManifest is [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getManifest).

Answer (score 2):

The object returned by this api `chrome.app.getDetails()` is simply the object form of the manifest.
You can access any of these variables:

```
{
  // Required
  "name": "My Extension",
  "version": "versionString",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  // Recommended
  "description": "A plain text description",
  "icons": { ... },
  "default_locale": "en",

  // Pick one (or none)
  "browser_action": {...},
  "page_action": {...},
  "theme": {...},
  "app": {...},

  // Add any of these that you need
  "background": {"persistent": false, ...},
  "background": {"persistent": true, ...},
  "chrome_url_overrides": {...},
  "content_scripts": [...],
  "content_security_policy": "policyString",
  "file_browser_handlers": [...],
  "homepage_url": "http://path/to/homepage",
  "incognito": "spanning" or "split",
  "intents": {...}
  "key": "publicKey",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "versionString",

  "nacl_modules": [...],
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "omnibox": { "keyword": "aString" },
  "options_page": "aFile.html",
  "permissions": [...],
  "plugins": [...],
  "requirements": {...},
  "update_url": "http://path/to/updateInfo.xml",
  "web_accessible_resources": [...],
  "sandbox": [...]
}
```

by simply calling:

```
var deets = chrome.app.getDetails();
console.log(deets.name);
console.log(deets.description);
console.log(deets.version);
//etc...
```